# Spring-MVC - Error creating bean with name 'procesarController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I am having a problem with spring , when launching the app in the server I have this error message, please help Thanks in advance!!.

Error Message

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'procesarController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.zonagifts.web.service.TransaccionService com.zonagifts.web.controller.ProcesarController.transaccionService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'TransaccionService' defined in file [C:\Users\Adolfo\Desktop\ZonacardEstableciemiento\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Webzonagifts\WEB-INF\classes\com\zonagifts\web\service\TransaccionServiceImpl.class]: Post-processing failed of bean type [class com.zonagifts.web.service.TransaccionServiceImpl] failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [com.zonagifts.web.service.TransaccionServiceImpl] for resource metadata: could not find class that it depends on
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.zonagifts.web.service.TransaccionService com.zonagifts.web.controller.ProcesarController.transaccionService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'TransaccionService' defined in file [C:\Users\Adolfo\Desktop\ZonacardEstableciemiento\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Webzonagifts\WEB-INF\classes\com\zonagifts\web\service\TransaccionServiceImpl.class]: Post-processing failed of bean type [class com.zonagifts.web.service.TransaccionServiceImpl] failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [com.zonagifts.web.service.TransaccionServiceImpl] for resource metadata: could not find class that it depends on
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

My servlet.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.zonagifts.web" >
        <context:include-filter type="aspectj" expression="com.zonagifts.*"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper" />
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" cache-period="604800" />
    <mvc:view-controller path="/error" view-name="error" />

    <bean id="viewResolver1"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="objectMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper" />


    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="es" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My controller is

```
package com.zonagifts.web.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import com.zonagifts.web.domain.ResponseServicio;
import com.zonagifts.web.domain.Usuario;
import com.zonagifts.web.service.TransaccionService;
import com.zonagifts.web.util.Constantes;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("procesar")
public class ProcesarController {


    @Autowired
    private TransaccionService transaccionService;

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value="activar",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseServicio activarTarjeta(HttpSession sesion,String numeroTarjeta){

        ResponseServicio responseServicio=new ResponseServicio();
        Usuario usuario=(Usuario) sesion.getAttribute(Constantes.SESION_USUARIO_ZONA_CARDS);
        if(usuario != null){
            String [] respuesta=transaccionService.activarTarjeta(numeroTarjeta, usuario.getCodigoComercio(), usuario.getCodigoTerminal(), Constantes.TRANSACCION);
            responseServicio.setRespuesta(respuesta[0]);
            responseServicio.setCodigoOperacion(respuesta[1]);
            responseServicio.setMensaje(respuesta[2]);
        }
        return responseServicio;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="anular",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseServicio anular(HttpSession sesion,String numeroTarjeta){

        ResponseServicio responseServicio=new ResponseServicio();
        Usuario usuario=(Usuario) sesion.getAttribute(Constantes.SESION_USUARIO_ZONA_CARDS);
        if(usuario != null){
            String [] respuesta=transaccionService.anularTarjeta(numeroTarjeta, usuario.getCodigoComercio(), usuario.getCodigoTerminal(), Constantes.TRANSACCION);
            responseServicio.setRespuesta(respuesta[0]);
            responseServicio.setCodigoOperacion(respuesta[1]);
            responseServicio.setMensaje(respuesta[2]);
        }
        return responseServicio;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="consumo",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseServicio consumo(HttpSession sesion,String numeroTarjeta,String codigoSeguridad,String monto){

        ResponseServicio responseServicio=new ResponseServicio();
        Usuario usuario=(Usuario) sesion.getAttribute(Constantes.SESION_USUARIO_ZONA_CARDS);
        if(usuario != null){
            String [] respuesta=transaccionService.consumirSaldo(numeroTarjeta, codigoSeguridad, usuario.getCodigoComercio(), usuario.getCodigoTerminal(), monto, Constantes.TRANSACCION);
            responseServicio.setRespuesta(respuesta[0]);
            responseServicio.setCodigoOperacion(respuesta[1]);
            responseServicio.setMensaje(respuesta[2]);
            //responseServicio.setIdTransaccion(respuesta[3]);
        }
        return responseServicio;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="saldo",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseServicio saldo(HttpSession sesion,String numeroTarjeta){

        ResponseServicio responseServicio=new ResponseServicio();
        Usuario usuario=(Usuario) sesion.getAttribute(Constantes.SESION_USUARIO_ZONA_CARDS);
        if(usuario != null){
            String [] respuesta=transaccionService.consultarSaldo(numeroTarjeta, usuario.getCodigoComercio(), usuario.getCodigoTerminal(), Constantes.TRANSACCION);
            responseServicio.setRespuesta(respuesta[0]);
            responseServicio.setCodigoOperacion(respuesta[1]);
            responseServicio.setMensaje(respuesta[2]);
        }
        return responseServicio;
    }

}
```

TransactionServiceImpl

```
package com.zonagifts.web.service;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.tempuri.GiftCardsSoapProxy;
import com.zonagifts.api.util.Util;
import com.zonagifts.web.controller.LoginController;

@Service
public class TransaccionServiceImpl implements TransaccionService {

    private static GiftCardsSoapProxy giftCardsSoapProxy; 

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class);

    public String[] activarTarjeta(String numeroTarjeta, String codigoComercio,
            String codigoTerminal, String idTransaccion) {

        String token =tarjeta.concat(comercio).concat(terminal).concat(transaccion).concat(pass);
        Object response=null;
        try {
            giftCardsSoapProxy=new GiftCardsSoapProxy();
            response = giftCardsSoapProxy.activar_tarjeta(numeroTarjeta.trim(),
                    codigoComercio.trim(), codigoTerminal.trim(), 
                    idTransaccion.trim(), token);

        } catch (RemoteException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String[] res = (String[]) response;
        return res ;
    }

    public String[] anularTarjeta(String numeroTarjeta, String codigoComercio,
            String codigoTerminal, String idTransaccion) {
        String token =tarjeta.concat(comercio).concat(terminal).concat(transaccion).concat(pass);
        Object response=null;
        try {
            giftCardsSoapProxy=new GiftCardsSoapProxy();
            response = giftCardsSoapProxy.anular_tarjeta(numeroTarjeta.trim(),
                    codigoComercio.trim(), codigoTerminal.trim(), 
                    idTransaccion.trim(), token);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String[] res = (String[]) response;
        //guardarTransaccionBD(tx);
        return res ;
    }

    public String[] consumirSaldo(String numeroTarjeta, String codigoSeguridad,
            String codigoComercio, String codigoTerminal, String montoConsumir,
            String idTransaccion) {
        String token =tarjeta.concat(codSeguridad).concat(comercio).concat(terminal).concat(monto).concat(transaccion).concat(pass);
        Object response=null;
        try {
            giftCardsSoapProxy=new GiftCardsSoapProxy();
            response = giftCardsSoapProxy.consumir_tarjeta(numeroTarjeta.trim(),
                    codigoSeguridad.trim(),codigoComercio.trim(), 
                    codigoTerminal.trim(),montoConsumir.trim(), idTransaccion.trim(), token);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String[] res = (String[]) response;
        return res ;
    }

    public String[] consultarSaldo(String numeroTarjeta, String codigoComercio,
            String codigoTerminal, String idTransaccion) {
        String token =tarjeta.concat(comercio).concat(terminal).concat(transaccion).concat(pass);
        Object response=null;
        try {
            giftCardsSoapProxy=new GiftCardsSoapProxy();
            response = giftCardsSoapProxy.consultar_saldo(numeroTarjeta.trim(),
                    codigoComercio.trim(), codigoTerminal.trim(), 
                    idTransaccion.trim(), token);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String[] res = (String[]) response;
        return res ;
    }



}
```

TransaccionService

```
package com.zonagifts.web.service;

public interface TransaccionService {

    String[] activarTarjeta(String numeroTarjeta,String codigoComercio,String codigoTerminal,String idTransaccion);

    String[] anularTarjeta(String numeroTarjeta,String codigoComercio,String codigoTerminal,String idTransaccion);

    String[] consumirSaldo(String numeroTarjeta,String codigoSeguridad,String codigoComercio,String codigoTerminal,String montoConsumir,String idTransaccion);

    String[] consultarSaldo(String numeroTarjeta,String codigoComercio,String codigoTerminal,String idTransaccion);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the final exception that you get is the following:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [com.zonagifts.web.service.TransaccionServiceImpl] for resource metadata: could not find class that it depends on

Looking at your TransaccionServiceImpl class, there are a few things that could be missing from your class path...

- org.tempuri.GiftCardsSoapProxy
- com.zonagifts.web.controller.LoginController

There are others, but these are the two that give me the most pause.

Could you verify that these two files (or their jar files) are in your deployed classpath?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your *My servlet.xml* I found that you didn't have the context:annotation-config tag. As you are using annotations to wire your beans you need to have this tag in your xml.

```
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
```

As there is a single Implementation for the interface and the component scanning is turned on, I don't think you will need to qualify the bean. But if app doesn't work even after adding the context:annotation-config tag, try to qualify the bean. You can qualify as follows

Annotate the *TransaccionServiceImpl* class with @service("transaccionServiceImplBean") and when you wire it in *ProcesarController* provide the qualifier as below

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("transaccionServiceImplBean")
private TransaccionService transaccionService;
```

Comment: Thanks Aditya, but I tried it and it doesn't seem to be working for me

Comment: If you are in eclipse can you go to Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path and select the Source and see if you have YourProject/src folder in there? If possible can you tell what folders you see in the Source.

Comment: I'm using spring tool suite, the folders on source are src/main/java, src/main/resources and src/test/java